# What specific modules are included in Drupal Commerce Kickstart?

Tags: 7, commerce

[Drupal Commerce Kickstart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) is a project built on Drupal Commerce that bundles Drupal 7, Commerce and a host of additional modules with some preset settings to speed up Commerce-based development.

I'm trying to find out what specific modules are actually included in this bundle, but all I can find is [uninformative advert pages like this](https://commerceguys.com/product/commerce-kickstart).

There's nothing about what exactly is included in the [Kickstart documention](https://www.drupal.org/node/1291116). The closest I can find elsewhere online is [this list of modules *not* included](http://fuseinteractive.ca/blog/8-modules-commerce-kickstart-didnt-include-should-be-your-commerce-site).

Is there any simple list of the modules that are bundled in the Commerce Kickstart package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the actual makefile that builds the latest version of Commerce Kickstart.

http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce_kickstart/tree/drupal-org.make

Within it, you can find every module that is built in. It includes the machine name of the project and the version number used.

For example, the entry "projects[ctools][version] = 1.9" shows you the machine name ctools, which is the Chaos Tools module, and the version is 1.9. You can look up the modules on drupal.org by substituting the machine name into the following URL: http://drupal.org/project/MACHINENAME.

Answer (score 0):

This is a list based on [this page announcing the first release candidate for Commerce Kickstart 2 in 2012](https://commerceguys.com/blog/approaching-first-stable-release-commerce-kickstart-v2) of modules that were developed as part of Commerce Kickstart and subsequently released as independent modules.

It gives an overview of some of the non-standard modules most specific to Kickstart. Note it's not complete and may not be up to date, but might be a useful starting point for understanding what sort of things Kickstart adds to a typical Drupal site.

### Modules

- [Commerce Backoffice](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_backoffice)
- [Commerce Search API](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_search_api)
- [Commerce add to cart confirmation](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_add_to_cart_confirmation)
- [Inline Entity Form](http://drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form)
- [Views Megarow](http://drupal.org/project/views_megarow)
- [Field Extractor](http://drupal.org/project/field_extractor)
- [Commerce Fancy Attributes](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_fancy_attributes)
- [Image Delta Formatter](http://drupal.org/project/image_delta_formatter)
- [Commerce Addressbook](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_addressbook)

### Themes

- [Omega Kickstart](http://drupal.org/project/omega_kickstart) - a branch of the Omega theme
- [Shiny](http://drupal.org/project/shiny) - an admin theme